# How to avoid repeating the JSDoc on both a signature and an implementation of a function?

Tags: typescript, types, declare

I don't understand what should I use — `type` or `declare` in this case. With `declare`, JSDoc comments are shown in the IDE, but not the `type` JSDoc comments.

Regardless of that, is there a way to not repeat the same JSDoc (the one in the method and `type` or `declare`)?

It is an example of my code:

**Code with `type`:**

```typescript
/**
 * Return a string TYPE
 * @returns string
 */
type getName = (name: string) => void;

interface iUseHook {
    getName: getName;
}

function useHook (): iUseHook {

    /**
     * Return a string METHOD
     * @returns string
     */
    const getName = function (name: string): string {
        return name;
    }

    return {
        getName
    }
}

const tryingHook = useHook();
tryingHook.getName('Mark');
```

**Code with `declare`:**

```typescript
/**
 * Return a string DECLARE
 * @returns string
 */
declare function getName (name: string): void;

interface iUseHook {
    getName: typeof getName;
}

function useHook (): iUseHook {

    /**
     * Return a string METHOD
     * @returns string
     */
    const getName = function (name: string): string {
        return name;
    }

    return {
        getName
    }
}

const tryingHook = useHook();
console.log(tryingHook.getName('Mark'));
```

Comment: Which IDE? JSDoc for types works as normal even in the Playground. Of note is a small misunderstanding of what `declare` is for - it is only to be used in *ambient* contexts (f.e., declaration files, .d.ts), it is not supposed to be used in TypeScript source files (unless you need to prototype something or declare a function / variable that you know exists at runtime, but there are no type packages available [even that is an edge case and is better handled with `declare module` or `global` augmentation]).